# How to keep div elements from overlapping parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have tried setting overflow to hidden, but this cuts off the images that end up overlapping the parent div. I'd like them to be contained within the parent div without being cut off. What value should I adjust to achieve this?

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/bLm9antL/1/)

```
body {
  font-family: Europa;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: solid #6441a5;
  background:#6441a5;
}

div {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

  div img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.results-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: The .box have a fixed height of 500px so what exactly should happen to the DIVs that does not fit in the box? Your options are hidden (which you don't like), scroll bar or remove the height and let it grow in height.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the fixed `height` of your `div.box` and then add `display: block` to your `img` so that they are stacked one below another

```css
body {
  font-family: Europa;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: solid #6441a5;
  background:#6441a5;
}

div {
  padding: 10px;
}

  div img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  display:block;
}

.results-wrap {
}
```

```html
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class ="results-wrap">
        <div class="results"><img src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQyBVE0UKugTT3yaJZ7fpr1nVK_RC9R5853AodqdLWMcsDl4PQw'/>
        <img src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQyBVE0UKugTT3yaJZ7fpr1nVK_RC9R5853AodqdLWMcsDl4PQw'/>
        <img src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQyBVE0UKugTT3yaJZ7fpr1nVK_RC9R5853AodqdLWMcsDl4PQw'/>
        <img src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQyBVE0UKugTT3yaJZ7fpr1nVK_RC9R5853AodqdLWMcsDl4PQw'/>
        <img src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQyBVE0UKugTT3yaJZ7fpr1nVK_RC9R5853AodqdLWMcsDl4PQw'/>
        <img src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQyBVE0UKugTT3yaJZ7fpr1nVK_RC9R5853AodqdLWMcsDl4PQw'/>
        <img src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQyBVE0UKugTT3yaJZ7fpr1nVK_RC9R5853AodqdLWMcsDl4PQw'/>
        <img src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQyBVE0UKugTT3yaJZ7fpr1nVK_RC9R5853AodqdLWMcsDl4PQw'/>
        
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your .box height must be fixed at 500px or not

```
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  /*height: 500px;*/
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: solid #6441a5;
  background:#6441a5;
}
.results-wrap {
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLm9antL/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Make them smaller so they can fit or just remove the images that don't fit:

```
div img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

Js Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bLm9antL/7/